# pass multi-dimensional array from controller to view codeignighter

Tags: codeigniter, multidimensional-array

how do i pass a multi diminutional array to a view?
controller code

```
       public function index(){

           data['navs'] =   array( 
            'name' => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
            'link' => array('one', 'two', 'three'));

            $this->load->view('adminView', $data);}
```

view code

```
        <?php if ($navs) {
                foreach ($navs as $nav) {
                echo('<li><a href="' . $nav->link . '">' . $nav->name . '</a></li>');
                }
            }?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to build the array, the right way. It should be something like:

```
$data['navs'] = array( array(  'name'    =>  'one',
                               'link'    =>  'linkone'),

                       array(  'name'    =>  'two',
                               'link'    =>  'linktwo')    
                    );
$this->load->view('adminView', $data);
```

Then in your view:

```
foreach($navs as $n){
  echo "<li><a href='{$n['link']}'>{$n['name']}</a></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once in the view, refer to your data as array elelements, not object properties (you are passing the array of arrays, not array of objects). Based on your controller, your view code should look like that:

```
foreach ($navs as $nav) {
    echo('<li><a href="' . $nav['link'] . '">' . $nav['name'] . '</a></li>');
}
```

However, that won't output the right result because your $nav['link'] and $nav['name'] are two arrays. You'd need to call any of their elements or change controller accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

how to fetch dynamic array value by using controller of codeigniter in php

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => Wellness & Spa
    [isSelected] => true
    [subModules] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Spa1
                    [isSelected] => true
                    [0] => object:81
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Spa2
                    [isSelected] => true
                    [0] => object:82
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Wellness
                    [isSelected] => true
                    [0] => object:83
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying. Please give some more context.